# find and delete a word in a text by batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, find

Hi all I want to find and delete some word by a batch file i tried this:

```
@Echo OFF
REM Set These Variables
SET "InFile=Unloaded.txt"
SET "OutFile=NowLoaded.txt"
SET "Replace=%r%"
SET "ReplaceWith=  "

REM Get Total Lines Number [including empty lines]
FOR /F %%A IN ('TYPE "%InFile%"^|find /v /c ""') DO SET "Till=%%A"

REM Create The OutFile with changes
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!InFile!" (
  FOR /L %%a IN (1 1 0) DO SET /p "="
  FOR /L %%A IN (1 1 %Till%) DO (
    SET "line="
    SET /P "line="
    IF "!line!x" == "x" ( Echo.
   ) ELSE ( Echo !line:%Replace%=%ReplaceWith%!)
  )
)>>"%OutFile%"

ENDLOCAL
```

but in out put instead of delete that says Echo Is Off.
please help me thanks.

Comment: In this line `SET "Replace=%r%"` what is the value of `r` and where is it defined? If you want to replace literal `%r%` text (not a variable named `r`) then it should be `%%r%%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat).You can use it by like this to delete a word in text file:

```
call replacer.bat text.txt "word" ""
```

More powerful solutions are [JREPL.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) and [FindRepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697).