# How to remove some words from text files?

Tags: batch-file

Following is my code of a batch file in windows.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist raw_scores.csv del raw_scores.csv
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set i=0
    for /F "delims=" %%l in (%%f) do (
        set /A i+=1
        set line!i!=%%l
    )
    echo %%f, !line2!, !line1!, !line4! >> raw_scores.csv
)
```

Following is the outcome of batch file in windows in csv format.

```
quiz_result_2018-02-08_05-34-20.txt  User Name: manoj    Quiz Name: Physics  User Score: 53
quiz_result_2018-02-08_06-02-05.txt  User Name: Pooja    Quiz Name: Chemistry    User Score: 61
quiz_result_2018-02-08_06-07-11.txt  User Name: Temujin  Quiz Name: Biology  User Score: 93
```

Now I want to remove some words from the final outcome in csv file. These are `"User Name:", "Quiz Name:", "User Score:"`. So, it will look like...

```
quiz_result_2018-02-08_05-34-20.txt manoj   Physics 53

quiz_result_2018-02-08_06-02-05.txt Pooja   Chemistry   61

quiz_result_2018-02-08_06-07-11.txt Temujin Biology 93
```

Comment: May this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494947/find-and-delete-a-word-in-a-text-by-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo %%f, !line2:user name:=!, !line1:quiz name:=!, !line4:score:=! >> raw_scores.csv
```

should remove the text as required, assuming those strings appear on the lines.

Your report however does not contain the <kbd>,</kbd>s that the code indicates. Please post example data *exactly* as it appears.